# Z-Index issue in Mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, mobile, safari, z-index

The site is: http://matthamil.com/Hamloo/

It's the section with the `H2` that says "Our Approach."

I'm trying to add a grey `div` that will be positioned behind the last `.services-box div ("Manage Results" box)`, but I want it to be on top of the `#our-approach div`. However, I can't get the `.light-grey-bg div` to even show up on Mobile Safari.

The CSS:

```
#our-approach {
    background-color: #464646;
}

.services-box {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    float: center;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}

.inner-box {
    color: #262628;
    background-color: #262628;
    width: 80%;
    height: 600px;
    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}

.light-grey-bg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-250px);
    transform: translateY(-250px);
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position elements in 3D space with `-webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);`; this will lift them above all other elements (which are z-position 0px).

Note that this is a 100% separate concept from the `z-index` CSS property which defines the stacking order in the local stacking context.

Comment: How are you inserting the light-grey-bg div into your html? It's not visible in the source.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm dumb. I forgot to reupload my updated html file. It is visible now.